# Catching SQL errors and preventing a form from being submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, postgresql

I have a little application that allows users to search for locations on a mac submit comments to a CartoDB SQL database (PostgreSQL) http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html using an HMTL form, JavaScript and SQL (and a little PHP to make the API connection to CartoDB). It works great for vast majority of users, but some submissions are not coming through.

I have no idea why the SQL submissions are working sometimes and not others, works perfectly every time for me. Although I have tracked one issue down to Safari 5.1, but I think it must be happening in other browsers too. The main problem is I can't see any errors ANYWHERE, so it's impossible to track down.

**So here are my questions:**

**1. Is there any way of catching SQL errors and preventing the form from being submitted?**

**2. Is there any way of seeing SQL errors so I can track down the problem?**

Below is a snippet of the code I am using to submit the comments:

```
var tblName = "comment_collection"
var usrName = "***dney"

// FORM 
$("#allSubmitBtn").click(function (e) {
    //CHECK IF has a comment
    if (!notEmpty(document.getElementById('description1'))) {
        alert('Please enter a comment.');
        return false;
    }
    if (!notEmpty(document.getElementById('latlongit1'))) {
        alert('Sorry, there has been an error, please search for a location again.');
        return false;
    } else {
        currentNeighborhood = $('#neighborhoodName1').val();
        parcel = $('#parcel_id1').val();
        address = $('#pre_address1').val();
        userAddress = $('#UserAddress1').val();
        phoneNum = $('#phone1').val();
        emailAdd = $('#emailAddress1').val();
        userType = $('#userType1').val();
        otherUser = $('#otherUserType1').val();
        currentDescription = $('#description1').val();
        latlongy = $("input[name='latlongit1']").val();
        explainType = $('#explainType').val();
        currentProject = selectedCity.name;
        commentType = new Array();
        $("input:checkbox[name=commentType]:checked").each(function () {
            commentType.push($(this).val());
        });

        var sql = "INSERT INTO " + tblName + " (the_geom, project, description, name,comment_address,parcel_id,phone_number,email_address,comment_type,comment_type_other,user_type,user_type_other,profile_address,flag,loved) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('";
        // var a = layer.getLatLng();
        // console.log(a);
        var sql2 = '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[' + latlongy + "]}'),4326),'" + currentProject + "','" + (currentDescription.replace(/'/g, "''")).replace(/"/g, "''") + "','" + (currentNeighborhood.replace(/'/g, "''")).replace(/"/g, "''") + "','" + address + "','" + parcel + "','" + phoneNum + "','" + emailAdd + "','" + commentType + "','" + explainType + "','" + userType + "','" + otherUser + "','" + userAddress + "','false','0')";
        var pURL = sql + sql2;
        console.log(pURL);
        submitToProxy(pURL);
        alert("Your Comments have been submitted");

        return true;
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: inline sql within jquery - god only knows how awful that is...I mean I never even thought such a thing is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the Github repo the tutorial is based off. Security is a MAJOR issue and is mentioned right off the bat with this tutorial. It is more of an illustration than anything, anyone implementing it should modify the scripts to be more secure.

Check out this pull request and try to create a solution from it. It addresses the issue to a degree. It moves more of the query into the PHP scripts and only allows field names in from the browser.

https://github.com/enam/neighborhoods/pull/4

Answer (score 1):

This is incredibly dangerous/bad code. You're building sql on the client and sending it to the server to be executed. What's to stop someone from popping up their js console and doing `submitToProxy('DROP DATABASE DATABASE()')`?

Boom goes your site, boo hoo, too bad.

And even if you DON'T nuke this code from orbit, just to be sure it's really dead, and keep using it, you can't trap SQL exceptions, because they occur on the server, not in your client. At best your **SERVER** has to check for errors, and send back an appropriate message, e.g.

```
result = run_query(dangerous ql from user);
if (error occured) {
    return json_encode('error' => true, 'reason' => 'someone set us up the bomb'));
} else {
    return json_encode('error' => false, 'data' => query results);
}
```

and then your client-side ajax has to do

```
$.ajax(....
   success: function (data) {
      if (data.error) { alert('boom!'); }
      else {... do stuff with data ...}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the bad news instead of having me to explain it!

Comment: I am surprised to hear this - I obtained this code from this tutorial: http://duspviz.mit.edu/web-map-workshop/cartodb-data-collection/ and I thought that it was safe because it is using a secure connection to the data using PHP... I didn't know that people could execute SQL code in the console without the API connection?

Comment: well, if that's the in-browser sqlite db, then not such a big deal. but if that really is going to a server somewhere, then it's incredibly crappy code.

Comment: It's a private database hosted on CartoDB, so I don't know what kind of security measures they have in place? Also this page is only accessible to registered users, so that's another layer of security. However, I definitely don't want users to be able to clear out my database! Any suggestions on how to repair or patch this? I am definitely a PHP and SQL novice, so I have no clue how to fix this.